# Azure Functions proxy to url provided by querystring gives 404

Tags: proxy, azure-functions

I've set up an Azure Functions proxy (using `proxies.json`). This should just pick the value given in the original request's `url` query string parameter and use that as a value for `backendUri`. So the goal is that the response of the call to the proxy contains the response of calling the URL that's in the `url` query string parameter directly. I need this because of CORS.

Here's my `proxies.json`

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "proxy1": {
      "debug": true,
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": ["GET"],
        "route": "/proxy/"
      },
      "backendUri": "{request.querystring.url}"
    }
  }
}
```

When I call the proxy using https://not-an-actual-url.azurewebsites.net/proxy/?url=https://stackoverflow.com I'm getting back a 404. Same if I encode the value of the `url` parameter. If I set the `backendUri` in `proxies.json` to a static URL instead of trying to use the query string, it works, however.

To summarize, I want the value of `backendUri` to depend on the URL of the original request. As stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) this should be possible. Quote from the docs:

> Set the backend URL to another endpoint. This endpoint could be a function in another function app, or it could be any other API. The value does not need to be static, and it can reference application settings and parameters from the original client request.

Answer (score 0):

> When I call the proxy using
> https://not-an-actual-url.azurewebsites.net/proxy/?url=https://stackoverflow.com
> I'm getting back a 404. Same if I encode the value of the url
> parameter. If I set the backendUri in proxies.json to a static URL
> instead of trying to use the query string, it works, however.

Judging from your problem description, you don't seem to have a real HttpTrigger. You want to use function app as a server to forward requests to an address, right?

I think it is unrealistic that you want to dynamically get the url from the request and apply it to proxies.json. Because this file is already loaded when the function app is started, you cannot let the requested information enter, it will read your value as a normal string, if it is not a direct url, it cannot be read.

For CORS, you can find some free and public servers for forwarding, or build a server for forwarding by yourself. The proxies.json of function app may not realize your idea.

Comment: Thank you, @bowman-zhu, for your answer. Yes, I don't have a real HttpTrigger, just using the `proxies.json`. I understand you mean that `backendUri` in `proxies.json` can only be a static value without any variables **coming from the original request**. This contradicts what's stated in the docs tough (see the text in my updated question).

Comment: @Christian OK, I see it, will check.